# Pandas: Group by Single Column Entries

Tags: python, dataset, pandas, data-table

[image]

So have this table above. I'm trying to aggregate the occupations such that the table results in:

[image]

I've tried using `df.groupby(['Occupation'])` but I get an error.
All I know is that my final step would be to set the index to "Occupation". But I still don't know how to group via entries in the single Occupation column here.

Also, what type of table would the final table be name/called?

I know it's not called a mutiindex table because there is only one index that the results are being grouped by.

Comment: It seems you're not applying any function to aggregate each group.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue might occur if you didn't tell that the second row in the table should also be considered a header line.

To address this, try to reset the header at the beginning.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('YOUR/FILE/DIRECOTRY.csv', skiprows=1) // ignore the 2nd row (0-indexed)
df.rename(columns={0:'Index'}, inplace=True) // optional
df.groupby(['Occupation'])
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the help!